# How To Get A Value When Swiping Picture on Safari Within App iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, safari, uiwebviewdelegate

I hava an app that launches Safari within the app. I can detect whether a link has been clicked or a searched being performed on the Safari.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    //NSLog(@"uiwebview navigation type: %d", navigationType);
    NSString *strNewURL = @"";
    NSString *strURL = @"";
    NSString *strBody = @"";
        switch (navigationType) {
            case 0:
                NSLog(@"UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked:");
                break;
            case 1:
                NSLog(@"UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted:");
                break;
            case 2:
                NSLog(@"UIWebViewNavigationTypeBackForward:");
                break;
            case 3:
                NSLog(@"UIWebViewNavigationTypeReload:");
                break;
            case 4:
                NSLog(@"UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormResubmitted:");
                break;
            case 5:
                NSLog(@"UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther:");
                break;

        default:
            break;
    }
return YES;
```

}

However, I have no idea on how to detect when a picture is being swiped(Say there is an image in the centre of your page. When you swipe, it changes to next/previous image on the same page). And whether is it possible to get the name of the image or the URL of the image?

**Note:**

- Swiping does not change the URL

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do that. Is swiping changing the URL?

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo Nope. Swiping does not change the URL.